# Ширина блока относительно высоты

Tags: css, веб-программирование

В интернете много информации о том, как задать блоку высоту относительно его ширины, но я совсем не смог найти как задать ширину относительно высоты.

Существует горизонтальная карточка фиксированной ширины с картинкой слева и некоторым текстом справа. Как мне оставлять контейнер картинки с соотношением сторон 1:1, при условии, что текстовая часть растягивает карточку по высоте

Comment: По-моему это даже теоретически невозможно... Если текст занимает по ширине оставшееся свободное место справа от картинки, значит ширина текста зависит от ширины картинки, а от ширины текста зависит его высота — в общем, текст зависит от картинки. Но если ширина картинки высчитывается с сохранением сторон относительно высоты текста, значит картинка зависит от текста. Но ведь высота текста уже и так зависит от ширины картинки! Получается замкнутая петля зависимостей размеров, которую невозможно решить (можно попытаться математически посчитать сходимость, но скорее всего выйдет бесконечность)

Comment: @andreymal, точно, спасибо за замечание, фиксированная ширина только у текстовой части карточки.

Comment: А такой вариант уже реальный, да (впрочем, не уверен, умеет ли css так делать)

Comment: [aspect-ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) тут не поможет?